# No module named 'uaclient' during `sudo apt upgrade` (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, python

I'm trying to upgrade my desktop from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.
(I regret not having upgraded it earlier before the ubuntu 16.04 EOL arrived. Two weeks ago I have upgraded two 16.04 notebooks to 18.04 though eventhough it was after the EOL, at that time there was just small problems I could solve).
I did `sudo apt update` but I'm getting the error below during `apt upgrade` after that.

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/prj/abdsn$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cpp-5-aarch64-linux-gnu cpp-aarch64-linux-gnu cuda-command-line-tools-10-0 cuda-compiler-10-0 cuda-cublas-10-0 cuda-cublas-dev-10-0 cuda-cudart-10-0
  cuda-cudart-dev-10-0 cuda-cufft-10-0 cuda-cufft-dev-10-0 cuda-cuobjdump-10-0 cuda-cupti-10-0 cuda-curand-10-0 cuda-curand-dev-10-0 cuda-cusolver-10-0
  cuda-cusolver-dev-10-0 cuda-cusparse-10-0 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-0 cuda-documentation-10-0 cuda-driver-dev-10-0 cuda-gdb-10-0
  cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-0 cuda-libraries-10-0 cuda-libraries-dev-10-0 cuda-license-10-0 cuda-memcheck-10-0 cuda-misc-headers-10-0 cuda-npp-10-0
  cuda-npp-dev-10-0 cuda-nsight-10-0 cuda-nsight-compute-10-0 cuda-nvcc-10-0 cuda-nvdisasm-10-0 cuda-nvgraph-10-0 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-0 cuda-nvjpeg-10-0
  cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-0 cuda-nvml-dev-10-0 cuda-nvprof-10-0 cuda-nvprune-10-0 cuda-nvrtc-10-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-0 cuda-nvtx-10-0 cuda-nvvp-10-0
  cuda-samples-10-0 cuda-toolkit-10-0 cuda-tools-10-0 cuda-visual-tools-10-0 gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu-base gcc-5-cross-base libasan2-arm64-cross
  libatomic1-arm64-cross libc6-arm64-cross libc6-dev-arm64-cross libclang1-3.6 libgcc-5-dev-arm64-cross libgcc1-arm64-cross libgomp1-arm64-cross libgsoap8
  libitm1-arm64-cross libllvm3.6v5 libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libnunit-util2.6.3-cil libpng16-16 libpython-dbg libpython2.7-dbg libstdc++-5-dev-arm64-cross
  libstdc++6-arm64-cross libubsan0-arm64-cross libvncserver1 libxmu-dev libxmu-headers linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross python-dbg python-kerberos python2.7-dbg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0~16.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The command python is linked to python2.7 and python3 is linked to python3.5 using alternative system.(update-alternatives). What can I do next?

ADD :
I saw somewhere I have to reinstall opca-client so did this,

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade opcua-client
```

and then I saw a warning about pip version, so I did
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
and then
sudo pip3 install --upgrade opcua-client
but now see this error below :

```
....
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0~16.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.entitlements'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Force remove `ubuntu-advantage-tools`, it is not available for 16.04. `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all ubuntu-advantage-tools`.

Comment: @pLumo Execuse me, but why should I purge the package? Will it solve the problem?

Comment: After upgrading you can reinstall it. But before, you need to fix it.

Comment: Ah.. I tried you suggestion, but it also gives me :  No module named 'uaclient.apt'

Comment: Okay, sorry. Then I don't know how to fix the issue :-(

Comment: @pLumo, I ran do-release-upgrade yesterday. It didn't go smoothly and once it booted ok with the VNC window (with ubuntu 18.04). I was glad but when I rebooted (after just apt update. apt upgrade failed.) the boot process stuck. I met his 'low resolution video' but when I try to install or purge something I see 'No module named 'uaclient.apt' or 'uaclient.entitlements'' problem. Do you know how I can install the uaclient?

Comment: I tried https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-advantage-client/21788 to install ubuntu-advantage-tools, but even this is errored with No module named uaclient.apt message.

Comment: I am getting the same error. What did you do to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Chan-Kim,

A user on Reddit had a similar issue - I saw the solution earlier, which was to update the PYTHONPATH to include /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages and then perform the updates.

I have had complete success with this.

This is what I used in my system.

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}:/usr/bin/python:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

[the solution @ /r/linux4noobs/ - reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/n6lz01/ubuntuadvantagetools_causing_failure/gy4oepz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Hi! I have upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 so I can't check what my case was. but I chose your answer because you're a new contributor. Welcome!

Comment: Can confirm it works, I have tested on my Ubuntu 16.04. The only difference is that I switched to the root bash (`sudo su`) before running the `export` command.

Comment: I had a very similar problem after upgrading Xubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
The graphical software management packages didn't work anymore.

This works on the command line also for a regular user in my case.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the reason to cause this problem is that I have additional python distribution installed on my computer `/usr/local/bin/python3`, which comes before `/usr/bin/python3` in the search path.  I modified manually the post-installation and pre-remove script in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.postinst` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm` and replace `python3` with the complete path `/usr/bin/python3`.  This solved my problem.

Comment: This is the better fix than any of the above. Jame's solution would bugger up the python paths potentially for a long running bash terminal that can't just be turned off. Permanently fixing the bash profile too would bugger up python3 programs reliant on the local version. Thus just editing the configuration script for this package, which should have done in the first place, by fully qualifying the path instead of relying on an environment variable, is the proper fix.
Developers for the package should fully qualify the usage of "python3" commands within the script!  That's best practice!

Comment: this might have worked for my case, but I have since then upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 and cannot test it. thanks for the good info though.

Answer (score 5):

I got similar problem and this worked for me:

Removing the uat, process will not complete, maybe missing uaclient.apt

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

Then manually remove the uat by:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --purge ubuntu-advantage-tools
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

Then `dist-upgrade` or `do-release-upgrade` works fine for me. Upgraded to 18.04

Comment: the root as the problem is wrong system python3 version that is not compatible with `ubuntu-advantage-tool`, if possible upgrade system python3 should be done. 
After upgraded to ubuntu 18.04, the system suggest to run`autoremove` but this can break applications that still rely on old python (the outdated 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

You should install `opcua` and `opcua-client` with default python command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade opcua

python -m pip install --upgrade opcua-client
```

Comment: This is not relevant

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 0):

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_old

sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info

sudo apt-get update

Works for me